# OPENDCL (AUTOCAD): avoid exiting modeless dialog if [ENTER] is pressed

Tags: dialog, lisp, autocad, modeless

I was looking for a way to avoid exiting modeless dialogs in autocad (created by opendcl) when [ENTER] is pressed.

Any idea?

Thanks, 
Dennis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've implemented such a feature for the OpenDCL grid system. You have to activate the OnCancelClose function on your form. This is how I did it:

```
(defun c:MyFunction_Form1_OnCancelClose (Reason /)
    ;; Reason = 0 when Enter is pressed
    (if (= Reason 0)
        (progn
            ;; Shift active editing cell one row down
            (setq rowAndCol(dcl_Grid_GetCurCell MyFunction_Form1_revisions))
            (dcl_Grid_StartCellEdit MyFunction_Form1_revisions (1+ (car rowAndCol)) (cadr rowAndCol))
        )
    )

    ;; Reason = 1 when ESC key is pressed, or the closing button in the titlebar
    ;; is clicked. Hence, enter won't work to cancel the dialog
    (/= Reason 1)
)
```